# What is the use/meaning of hedder as an alternate to header

Tags: single-word-requests

I’ve been told that *hedder* is an acceptable way to refer to a *header* in journalism, but I can’t find any reference to it being a valid spelling or to whether it has the exact same meaning or might carry something like the distinction between *text* and *copy*.

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: You're looking for *hed*, which is a term of art in journalism meaning the same thing as headline. Others are *lede* (lead), *graf* (paragraph), and so on. See [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004380.html) for more.

Comment: So is `hed` a term but `hedder` isn't a real term and they should be using `hed`?

Comment: As I understand it, yes.

Comment: Interesting, still NGram has a very low usage of 'hed' compared to ' headline. I guess it is  be pure jargon.

Comment: [Please ‘never’ use   on ELU](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the magazines where I work, we use *hed*, *subhed*, and *dek* in copy that we transmit to the designer, to indicate how the actual text to be published should be styled—namely as a head[line] or title, as a subhead, and as a deck or large-type-size summary/intro sentence. The spelling of these text format identifiers is intentionally wrong so that no one is tempted to imagine that the first word is part of the title. For example,

> HED WEST TO THE LAND OF OPPORTUNITY

should be recognizable to any designer (and subsequent editor or proofreader) as a headline that begins with the word *WEST*. But since *hed*, *subhed*, *dek*, *lede*, and *graf* are spelled in these ways specifically to avoid accidental publication, they qualify as "valid spelling" only in a backward sense.

Much the same can be said for greeking text (which we also use): "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" is a valid spelling of the first five words of stock placeholder text—text that is there to show where the real text is supposed to go and (from the designer's perspective) how the filled page will look—but if you spelled the words "Loram ipson dulor sut amit," it would be hard to argue that the resulting text was full of typos.

Answer (score 1):

As Robusto notes in the comments:

> You're looking for *hed*, which is a term of art in journalism meaning the same thing as headline. Others are *lede* (lead), *graf* (paragraph), and so on. See [Language Log](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004380.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Actually *hedder* seems to be  a term difficult to find.  The only reference I can find  is on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hedder,%20Hedder,%20header,%20Header&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,hedder;,c0;.t1;,Hedder;,c0;.t1;,header;,c0;.t1;,Header;,c0), where the term appears to have a very limited usage with respect to *header'. 
Hope someone may have more information on this issue!

Comment: I found several references bu they are associated with horse racing

Answer (score 0):

The only connection I found is in '**shouting' headlines**, or

> when a certain typeface is used, as in "when the story is
>   exceptionally important is it necessary to "shout" with io-line
>   (120-point) type."

-Design and makeup of the newspaper / by Albert A. ... . Sutton, Albert Alton, 1906  &

**hedder**:

> **Coom hedder!** Addressed (as in shouted) to horses in a team. A.S. Eiim, come ; Hibep, hither. See "Ga oot!" or Ga oot. A.S. Tih ute, go
>   outwards! Addressed to horses in a team.

-A glossary of provincial words and phrases in use ... . Akerman, John Yonge, 1806-1873.

Coincidentally, newspaper boys were commonly used to 'shout' the headline stories